# Using "Operator Mono" with "Firacode"

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using operator mono font as my default font in vs code, now I want to add fira code font to it, but I don't know how to add it in order to make both of them work. I try to add the second font in font family settings but the second font seems to replace the current font.
How should I do that?

My current sitting :

"editor.fontFamily": "'Operator Mono' ",
 "editor.fontLigatures" : true

Answer (score 10):

You can also update your Operator Mono font to include ligatures. I wrote a project that merges custom ligatures into your existing font.

Check it out at https://github.com/kiliman/operator-mono-lig

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first font in the list of the `editor.fontFamily` setting will be the used font for all code. Only if this font does not exist on your computer it will fall back to the second font in that list and so forth. The `editor.fontLigatures: true` setting will only work if your chosen font supports font ligatures which I think 'Operator Mono' does not.

However there is a way to combine two different fonts in VSCode: https://medium.com/@zamamohammed/multiple-fonts-alternative-to-operator-mono-in-vscode-7745b52120a0

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Kiliman's project](https://github.com/kiliman/operator-mono-lig) on GitHub, which he referenced in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039182/4361713).

This will give you the most used Operator Mono styles together with FiraCode ligatures, all bundled nicely into one font.
As of now, some styles are not supported yet. For these, you can [merge two fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/490922/merging-two-fonts), eg Operator Mono and FiraCode manually. This will add all elements that are present in FiraCode but not in Operator Mono – read: ligatures – to Operator Mono.

This approach should work with all monospaced fonts where one supports ligatures and the other doesn't.

Below is a screenshot of the 'thin' / 'extra light' version of Operator Mono with the 'light' FiraCode ligatures.

[image: Operator Mono with FiraCode ligatures.]